# Exception error relating to method signature

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, spreadsheet, method-signature

I'm super new to JavaScript, am an editor by trade, but need to create a Google Calendar view from a Google Sheet for story assignments for my writers. I've gone through a tutorial on how to make this work and have fixed a number of problems with the code. I'm stuck on what I think is the final issue. It relates to the method signature. The error message is:

> Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,String,String,String)
>   don't match the method signature for
>   CalendarApp.Calendar.createAllDayEvent. (line 20, file "Code")

Here's the code. Can anyone help???

```js
function myFunction() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange ("N8").getValue();
    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

    var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("G8:L124").getValues();


    for (x=6; x<signups.length; x++) {

      var shift = signups[x];
      var author = shift[0];
      var newsletterdate = shift[1];
      var livedate = shift[2];
      var duetoproductiondate = shift[3];
      var duetocopyeditdate = shift[4];
      var duetocontenteditdate = shift[5];
      eventCal.createAllDayEvent(author, newsletterdate, livedate, duetoproductiondate, duetocopyeditdate, duetocontenteditdate);
    }
}
```

Comment: make your dates actual dates. use new Date() to make proper dates. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createAllDayEventSeries(String,Date,EventRecurrence,Object)

Comment: The events you should have a `startDate` and an `endDate` (a date for the start and another one for the end of the event). You are providing far too many dates here. If you need to have so many dates in an event, I'd suggest you to create different events for each row. Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, or at least an example of the values that each `shift` array contains?

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty lost right now. I've tried a bunch of things. I seem to be able to run the code now but it's not properly populating the calendar I set up for this. I think I'm going to give up on this calendar view. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no signature for this method that has 6 parameters. The maximum I noted was 5 on this documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app

You must review the arguments you are passing when calling the function and choose the most suitable method signature.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty lost right now. I've tried a bunch of things. I seem to be able to run the code now but it's not properly populating the calendar I set up for this. I think I'm going to give up on this calendar view. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: If I were you, I would search for a tutorial on this. Anyway, you're welcome, SueTroy. If this answer helped you somehow, please mark it as best answer.

Comment: Pedro, thanks. I have watched a number of tutorials on how to do this.